# How can I obtain the list of all tickets I submitted on SourceForge?

Tags: bug-trackers, sourceforge

I tried almost everything in the profile but don't see my tickets. The `Profile / activity` tab shows just "No activity to display". The closest I can get is `Account settings / Subscriptions`, which shows tickets I get notification from - but I might have unsubscribed from my own tickets, so it might be that some are not listed.

PS: I have added new ticket now and at least I see that it is added to subscriptions automatically. But this is not sufficient.